# SPARQL concat plus group_concat on multiple fields

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

I have the following RDF structure that I cannot change:
[image]

Multiple Assignments can be associated to each employee (Manager). The output I'd like would be (including the word "in" and "&):

```
Employee Name   | Assignment

Name 1          | Assignment1 in Location1 & Assignment2 in Location2 &....
Name 2          | Assignment1 in Location2 & Assignment3 in Location1 &....
```

Is there a way to do this in `Sparql`?

This is what I have so far:

```
select ?name group_concat(DISTINCT ?description; separator("&"))
where
{
  ?employee :hasName ?name
  {
  select concat(?name, "In", ?location)
  ?employee ^:hasManager/:hasAsstName ?name
  ?employee ^:hasManager/:hasLocation ?location
  }

}
```

This gives me empty employee name and lots of ?Descriptions. It does not seem to reflect what I was expecting.

Comment: Do you have a query that goes part of the way? If so, [edit] your question to include. If not: why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the nested query is fine, you should assign a variable there to group concatenate and then group the results for all not concatenated variables. The query should look something like this:

```
select ?name (group_concat(DISTINCT ?description; separator = " & ") as ?descriptions)
where
{
  ?employee :hasName ?name
  {
  select (concat(?name, " in ", ?location) AS ?description)
  ?employee ^:hasManager/:hasAsstName ?name
  ?employee ^:hasManager/:hasLocation ?location
  }

}

GROUP BY ?name
```

Note the syntax for `GROUP_CONCAT`.

If you remove the subquery, it will be much faster. As I don't have your data, here's a very similar query on DBpedia, not using subquery:

```
SELECT ?name (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?SpouseInfo; separator = " & ") AS ?SpousesInfo)

{
    ?name a foaf:Person;
    dbo:spouse ?spouse.
    ?spouse dbo:residence/rdfs:label ?residence;
    rdfs:label ?spouse_name

    BIND (CONCAT(?spouse_name, " lives in ",?residence) AS ?SpouseInfo)
}
GROUP BY ?name
ORDER BY ?name

LIMIT 100
```

Here's [the result](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fname+%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT+%3FSpouseInfo%3B+separator+%3D+%22+%26+%22%29+AS+%3FSpousesInfo%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fname+a+foaf%3APerson%3B%0D%0Adbo%3Aspouse+%3Fspouse.%0D%0A%3Fspouse+dbo%3Aresidence%2Frdfs%3Alabel+%3Fresidence%3B%0D%0Ardfs%3Alabel+%3Fspouse_name%0D%0A%0D%0ABIND+%28CONCAT%28%3Fspouse_name%2C+%22+lives+in+%22%2C%3Fresidence%29+AS+%3FSpouseInfo%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Fname%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fname%0D%0ALIMIT+100%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Comment: Thanks! I missed out adding "as ?description".

Is there a better way to do this? The query seems to take a long time to execute and sometimes just times out.

Comment: Which triple store. How big is your data. group_concat is often expensive and depending on the implementation might block some optimizations.

Comment: You can speed it up by removing the nested query and bringing its content in the upper query.

Comment: Virtuoso; close to a billion triples. Are you'll sure that this is the right query logic, though?

Comment: I have provided an example with a very similar query on DBpedia. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yes, helps and works for my data as well. Thank you!

If anyone comes up with a way to this with enhanced performance, please let me know.

Comment: What`s wrong with the performance of the dbpedia query? Have you tried removing the subquery?

Comment: The dbpedia query works well. For my triple store, I expect around a million return triples on average. Because the external service that consumes the output of this query expects a full output I cannot use LIMITS and OFFSETS to break the output into smaller parts.

So far so good though. Things seem to be working. Thanks!